# double nesting with tidyverse and purrr

Tags: r, purrr, tidyverse

I´d like to create a double nested data structure, where c is nested in a which is further nested within id.

```
library(tidyverse)
m<-data_frame(id=c(100,101,100,101,100,101,100,101),
            a=c("A","A","B","B","A","A","D","D"),
            c=c(1:8))
m2 <- m %>%
group_by(id) %>%
nest(.key = one)
```

So the first nest is OK. But I´d like to further nest within m2$one.

any idea how I can do this?

I can go:

```
        m3 <- m2 %>%
              mutate(
                     two=map(m2$one,~(.x %>% 
                                      group_by(a) %>%
                                      nest(.key=two)))
              )
```

but this gives another column within m3, not within m2$one.

Comment: you should consider "traditional" R ; this is for instance a job for `split` and lists structures. i can't try here but something like `lapply(split(m, m$id), function(df) split(df, df$a))` may be a starting point

Comment: Does naming the column you make via `mutate` "one" instead of "two" give you the output you want?

Comment: @aosmith  Yep--It worked. Thx. If you write it up I'll approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the single-nested column `one` with the new double-nested column in `mutate` by assigning the same name (`one`) to the result rather than making a new column as you did.

```
m2 %>%
    mutate(one = map(one, ~.x %>% 
                        group_by(a) %>%
                        nest(.key = two)))
```